# Hydra cannot connect to http-post-form

Tags: passwords, http, password-cracking, hydra

I don't get the correct results and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
$ ./hydra -l admin -x 3:9:a http://localhost http-post-form "/admin/login:j_username=^USER^&j_password=^PASS^:failed" -s 8088             
Hydra v7.5 (c)2013 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2014-01-09 11:24:35
[WARNING] The service http has been replaced with http-head and http-get, using by default GET method. Same for https.
[WARNING] You must supply the web page as an additional option or via -m, default path set to /
[DATA] 16 tasks, 1 server, 5646683825432 login tries (l:1/p:5646683825432), ~352917739089 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
[ERROR] Child with pid 3320 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 6620 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 8496 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 9260 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 7440 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 6012 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 5368 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 6228 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 8104 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 7644 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 10152 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 2484 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4788 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 7948 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 9040 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 2648 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 6116 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 2684 terminating, can not connect
[ERROR] Too many connect errors to target, disabling http-get://localhost:80
0 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
[ERROR] 1 target did not resolve or could not be connected
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2014-01-09 11:24:47
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my test? My form at `http://localhost:8088/admin/login` looks like:

```
  <form name='f' class="marg-left" id="inputForm" method="post" action="j_spring_security_check" >
                       <br>
                   <h4 class="title">   <h4 class="loginfailed">
                       Login failed</h4>
                   Login</h4>
                   <label>
                       <span>Username</span>
                       <input id="id1" class="textInput" type="text" name="j_username" />
                   </label>
                   <label>
                       <span>Password</span>
                       <input class="textInput" type="password" name="j_password" />
                   </label>
                   <div class="buttons">
                       <button type="submit" >Login</button>
                       <button type="reset" >Reset</button>
                   </div>
                   </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've put the port option (`-s`) after the HTTP Post form URL and as a result Hydra is ignoring that option.

If you look at the message you can see it's trying to connect to port 80 (the default)

```
[DATA] attacking service http-get on port 80
```

I'd try [moving that `-s` option to earlier in the command line](https://en.kali.tools/?p=220), that'll probably sort it.